# Spring data rest - custom query with Page object

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest

When I use standard url for getting entities spring data rest adds Page object to json:

```
   "page": {
            "size": 20,
            "totalElements": 144429,
            "totalPages": 7222,
            "number": 0
        }
```

but when I wrote custom query

```
List<Mat> filter(@Param("mat")String mat, @Param("nazwam") String nazwam,
                        @Param("minExceeded") Integer minExceeded,
                        @Param("warehouseId") Integer warehouseId, @Param("groupId") Integer groupId, Pageable p);
```

Pagination (size=1&page=2&) is still working but the result doesn't contain information about total element count

Is there an option to enable this in custom queries?

Comment: I'm also facing this issue--were you able to find a workaround/solution for this?

Comment: Yes,the soluction is simple you need to change List<T> to Page<T>.